# Première et deuxième personnes du singulier sans le pronom « je » ou « tu »

Tags: usage, pronoms

Lorsqu'on utilise la première personne du singulier, il n'y a aucune ambiguïté sur le sujet, ce qui rend l'utilisation du pronom « je » toujours suffisante, et donc presque systématique. Il y a une tournure dans laquelle on ne l'utilise pas, quand on dit par exemple : « Moi, Pierre, refuse cela », pour insister sur le sujet.

Est-il correct d'utiliser une première personne du singulier sans le pronom « je », pour dire par exemple « Pierre suis d'accord » (si je suis Pierre) ? Ça sonne très étrange, et on a rarement besoin d'une telle tournure, mais je ne connais aucune règle de grammaire qui l'interdit.

La question se pose aussi pour la deuxième personne du singulier.

Comment: La règle de grammaire qui l'interdit est simplement la conjugaison... à la troisième personne, c'est "est" et pas "suis". Par contre rien ne vous empêche (grammaticalement ) de parler de vous à la troisième peronne, mais ca sonnera très pédant.

Comment: Ça ne sonne pas bien, pour insister à la première personne, je dirais "Moi, Pierre, suis d'accord", formule qui pourrait se rapprocher de l'usage de "Je soussigné, Pierre, suis d'accord".

Comment: Quand on veut insister sur le sujet, on doit nommer le sujet. *Moi* est le pronom tonique qui renforce *je* mais ne le remplace pas. Donc on dit *moi, Pierre, je refuse cela.*  Si on ne le nomme pas, possible mais la phrase est plutôt bancale, le pronom sujet est de toute façon sous-entendu et c'est avec ce sujet (ici, *je*) qu'on fait l'accord du verbe, qu'il soit ou non exprimé. Voir https://www.orthodidacte.com/conjugaison/conjuguer-c-est-toi-qui/

Answer (score 1):

Le prénom Pierre n'est pas le sujet de la phrase mais un attribut du sujet.

Dans la phrase "Moi, Pierre, suis d'accord", le sujet est "Moi" (1ere personne; sauf cas particulier voir commentaire de @None), et "Pierre" est l'attribut du sujet. Pour comprendre la construction grammaticale, on peut reformuler comme cela: "Moi, qui m'appelle Pierre, suis d'accord".

Comment: Le pronom réfléchi s'accorde avec le sujet, donc *moi, qui **m**'appelle Pierre je suis...*, *toi, qui **t**'appelles Pierre, tu es...*, *lui qui s'appelle Pierre, il est...*.  Par ailleurs dans ce genre de phrase le pronom tonique servant à insister, on reprend en général le sujet, mais ce n'est pas obligatoire, juste plus usuel, et s'il n'est pas repris le pronom tonique est le sujet.  Moi peut être sujet dans des phrases du genre : *– Moi, ça va, et toi ?*. Dans les phrases citées Pierre n'est pas une *troisième personne*, c'est un attribut du sujet, qui lui, est de la première personne.

Comment: Merci @None, je viens de corriger ma réponse

Comment: @None Pourquoi pas mettre une réponse avec vos deux commentaires? :)